# Exception trying to create delete request via MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(getContentResolver(), uris) for Android R (API 30) for scoped storage

Tags: java, android

Trying to target Android R (API 30) using scoped storage. I get the image picker to open the media library to allow user to select 1 or more images using:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

I get the list of Uris e.g.

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A189
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A190
```

I then attempt to generate the intent to ask permission to delete:

```
PendingIntent intent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(getContentResolver(), uris);
```

But this throws the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be referenced by specific ID
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:732)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2405)
    at android.provider.MediaStore.createRequest(MediaStore.java:822)
    at android.provider.MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(MediaStore.java:985)
    ...
```

How is one to convert the Uris into the special format expected by `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest`?

Comment: Your id's are 189 and 190 i think. Is this what is called batch deleting?

Comment: This is to get batch permission to delete multiple images. I know what the IDs are, I just don't know what the URI form the request is expecting. It seems odd to me that one service gives URIs that another service doesn't understand - or more appropriately the createDeleteRequest should be able to understand the URI of other older services.

Comment: Try ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_GET_CONTENT too. Maybe you have to take persistent uri permission first.(this is just a guess).

Answer (score 4):

In the end I re-generated the URI by extracting the media number from the returned URI and then using:

```
ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(num));
```

to create the URI expected by the MediaStore API. It seems strange that the image picker does not return the URI expected by other media services.

Comment: Talk about Google making this so weird. The URI's returned by various apps are all over the place.

Comment: How to get it media number from the returned URI ?

Comment: media  is always 0 when unisntall and reinstall app